# Why pagination request raise error adding calculating in map?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 8 app when in pagination request I use mapping with calculated new field :

```
$hostelDataRows   = Hostel
    ::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->where('hostels.id', 41) // debug
    ->with('state')
    ->with('region')
    ->with('user')
    ->withCount('hostelRooms')
    ->withCount('hostelInquiries')
    ->withCount('hostelImages')

    ->getByName($this->filters['name'], true)
    ->getByStatus($this->filters['status'], true)
    ->getByStateId($this->filters['state_id'], true)
    ->getByFeature($this->filters['feature'], true)
    ->addSelect([
        'min_hostel_rooms_price' =>
            HostelRoom::query()
                     ->selectRaw('MIN(price)')
                     ->whereColumn('hostel_id', 'hostels.id'),
    ])

    ->paginate($backend_per_page)
    ->map(function ($hostelItem) {
        if ($hostelItem->hostel_rooms_count > 0 and $hostelItem->hostel_inquiries_count > 0 and $hostelItem->hostel_images_count > 0 ) {
            $hostelItem->info_text = 'Has ' . ($hostelItem->hostel_rooms_count .  pluralize3( $hostelItem->hostel_rooms_count, 'no rooms', 'room', 'rooms' ) );
        }

        return $hostelItem;
    })
;
```

I got error :

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist. (
```

it is clear that with mappimg $hostelDataRows is not pagination object anyway...

How that can be fixed ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `map()` on a Paginator instance, you will get a `Collection` instance back (I think it is `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` here). So you can't put `map()` in front of it since that would require you to fetch the query (which is dependent on the paginator page). However there are some other solutions:

#### Solution 1: use the `tap()` helper

The `tap()` helper always returns the argument to the function. Since Collection `map()` (and `transform()` which is very similar) modify the instance Collection itself, this works as intended and you now get your original paginator instance back (with the extra properties from your map-function).

```php
return tap($query->paginate())->map(...);
```

#### Solution 2: use a `getInfoTextAttribute()` accessor

In your specific usecase you might just as well make a property for your `$hostelItem` if you are going to use this property more often, like so:

```php
// Models/HostelItem.php

/**
 * @property string $info_text
 */
class HostelItem extends Model
{
    public function getInfoTextAttribute()
    {
        return 'Has ' . ($this->hostel_rooms_count .  pluralize3( $this->hostel_rooms_count, 'no rooms', 'room', 'rooms' ) );
    }
}
```

I've added a `@property` annotation so you can have code assist in most of your files. Now, simply call `$hostelItem->info_text` and you're done. no need for a map.